# Solidity: Neither address.send nor address.transfer nor address.call is working

Tags: address.transfer

**Problem**

Whenever I call the paytest function (please see code snippet below) from javascript (please see code snippet below) i receive the below posted error message. Whether i use address.send, address.transfer or address.call, doesnt matter.Nothing works. I have plenty of test ETH on all accounts.

I use hardhat for my local blockchain.

Please help me. i am getting insane.

**Solidity Code**

```
    contract DC is ERC1155, Ownable {
    
    function paytest (address receiver, uint256 amount) public payable{
            (bool success, bytes memory _data) = payable(receiver).call{value:amount}("");
             require (success, "transaction failed");
             data=_data;
    }

    event Log(string fun, address sender, uint value, bytes data);

    fallback() external payable {
        emit Log("fallback", msg.sender, msg.value, msg.data);
    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit Log("receive", msg.sender,msg.value, "");
        
    }
```

**Javascript File**

```
   async function main () { // boiletplate function 
    
    
    const address = '0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9'; // actual contract address
    const DC = await ethers.getContractFactory('DC');
    const dc = await DC.attach(address);
    
    const [owner, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners(); 
    await dc.connect(addr1).paytest(address,ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"));
```

**Error message console**

```
C:\Users\Admin\hhtest>npx hardhat run --network localhost ./scripts/index.js
ProviderError: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'transaction failed'
    at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\Admin\hhtest\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:78:19)
    at GanacheGasMultiplierProvider.request (C:\Users\Admin\hhtest\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\gas-providers.ts:312:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small syntax error in your code. You cannot send the required ETH directly in the function like that. You have to send it in a different block under the name "value". So, instead of:

```
await dc.connect(addr1).paytest(address,ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"));
```

Try this,

```
await dc.connect(addr1).paytest(address,{ value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")});
```

Update: The other method I personally use to use convertWithDecimal() function when inputting the value of ETH. The function automatically handles the BigNumber errors.

```
const isInt = (n: any) => {
  return n % 1 === 0;
};

const convertWithDecimal = (value: any, decimal: any) => {
  if (value > 0) {
    if (isInt(value)) {
      value = parseInt(value);
      value = BigNumber(value).multiply(decimal);
    } else {
      value = value * decimal;
      value = toFixed(value);
      value = parseInt(value.toString().split(".")[0]);
      value = toFixed(value);
      value = BigNumber(value);
    }
    return value.toString();
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
};

const toFixed = (x: any) => {
  if (Math.abs(x) < 1.0) {
    var e = parseInt(x.toString().split("e-")[1]);
    if (e) {
      x *= Math.pow(10, e - 1);
      x = "0." + new Array(e).join("0") + x.toString().substring(2);
    }
  } else {
    var e = parseInt(x.toString().split("+")[1]);
    if (e > 20) {
      e -= 20;
      x /= Math.pow(10, e);
      x += new Array(e + 1).join("0");
    }
  }
  return x;
};
```

Just paste it in your JS file and when inputting ETH value, change the syntazx to this.

```
await dc.connect(addr1).paytest(address,{ value: convertWithDecimal(1, 10**18});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. it now throws another error:
C:\Users\Admin\hhtest>npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/index.js
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value={"value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0de0b6b3a7640000"}}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, 



  reason: 'invalid BigNumber value',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'value',
  value: { value: BigNumber { value: "1000000000000000000" } }
}

Comment: I updated the answer. Try this method.

Comment: This worked. I really really appreciate your help. thank you!!!

What I dont understand: why do i need to supply the amount as {value:} inside my .js file? 
To my understanding, the {value:} is already specified inside the paytest() smartcontract function. 
Why do i need to do this twice? I seem to miss something very fundamental

Comment: I am glad it worked. Whenever you create a function which accepts ETH, the ETH value is not passed in the arguments. Rather it is sent with the function, like a payload. So, in our JS file we need to mention that payload separately in the block. Mentioning how much ETH we will send along this method.